# Uploaded file not found in database

Tags: php, mysql

With this code I'm trying to upload a file to mysql database and then try and display it using another code (which I don't show here). The problem I'm having is that though this script executes, the uploaded file does not show.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <body>
      <div class="container" >
          <form action="insert.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <div class="col-sm-offset-3">
                  <h2>Application Results</h2>

                  <label for="fileSelect">Please upload your application results here:</label>

                  <input type="file" name="application_results" ><br>
            </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {    

     $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['application_results']['name'];
     $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

     $folder="uploads/";

      move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);
      $sql="INSERT INTO applications(application_results) VALUES('$file')";
      mysql_query($sql); 
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: add something like this `$savedLoc = $folder.$file ;` before `move_uploaded_file()` and insert `savedLoc` to DB. Check extention as well

Answer (score 1):

Please give permission to that uploads folder. Also it is better to have if condition before database insert. Adding if condition there will help you to identify if file is successfully uploaded or not.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file)) {
      $sql="INSERT INTO applications(application_results) VALUES('$file')";
      mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

If you have not solved this yet. Please try with tmp name.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['application_results']['tmp_name'],$folder.$file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {  

          $uploads = $_FILES['application_results'];

          $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['application_results']['name'];
          $folder = 'uploads/' . $file;

          if(move_uploaded_file($uploads['tmp_name'], $folder))
          {
               $sql="INSERT INTO applications(application_results) VALUES('$file')";
               mysql_query($sql); 
          }
    }
```